# Size classes don't work for extensions on iOS8/XCode Beta 7

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6, xcode6-beta7

I'm following the exact steps from this video (from 7:49 onwards): http://youtu.be/IwSTXY0awng?t=7m49s

The UIButton I'm adding to my view when changing the size class to, for example, portrait iPhone, always shows up. Note: only acts this way in extension mode (building a custom keyboard for example). When using a storyboard/view controller/app (exactly like the video), it works as expected.

Is this a bug or expected behaviour? Any work arounds?

Comment: I had the opposite, I was adding a layout for all iPhones in portrait (Final Values) but the layout never showed up on my iPhone 6. When switching to Base Values it did show up.